# AWS directory service vs. using STS to assume AWS IAM rule of enterprise identity federation

Tags: amazon-web-services

both of them are used to authorize from company network to use AWS resource. I do not know what is the difference btw them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AWS Directory Service for Microsoft Active Directory (Enterprise Edition), also known as AWS Microsoft AD, enables your directory-aware workloads and AWS resources to use managed Active Directory in the AWS Cloud. The Microsoft AD service is built on actual Microsoft Active Directory and does not require you to synchronize or replicate data from your existing Active Directory to the cloud.

see https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/

whereas STS:

> The AWS Security Token Service (STS) is a web service that enables you to request temporary, limited-privilege credentials for AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) users or for users that you authenticate (federated users).

see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

The AWS Directory Service is a full AD implementation which can "join" your in house servers.  This would work better if there is a VPN and/or AWS Direct Connect in place.  So replication occurs just as it would if you set up another Microsoft AD server

STS for linking your on premise accounts to AWS has some kind of shim software that is custom, running on premise.  In the case you are asking about the local on premise environment has AD. The custom software deals with authentication against a local AD, then negotiates temporary creditials with the AWS account.  AWS do custom software for this use case   see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-your-on-premises-active-directory-to-aws-using-ad-connector/

So the difference between them is

- AWS Directory Service sets up a new server on the cloud.  This has to be linked to your on premise equipment to get it to work.  It works better with a good link between on premise and AWS.  Could be a better fit if your are running Microsoft stack on AWS
- STS in this use case requires installing software on your on premise systems.  There is also configuration to the AWS account